# Can I do everything with OpenLayers mobile like OpenLayers API?

Tags: openlayers, mobile

Where can I download OpenLayers mobile API? 
Can I do everything with OpenLayers mobile like OpenLayers API?

Answer (score 4):

> OpenLayers.mobile.js - a mobile focused build --> Includes a subset of
>   the OpenLayers library to serve common mobile web app use cases. This
>   build provides access to OpenStreetMap, Bing, WMS, WFS and vector
>   layers; touch optimized controls; geolocation; vector editing and
>   interaction tools. The examples tagged mobile can use this build.

so it doesnt have lots of feature of openlayers.  if you want to learn what it has you can check out  from `openlayers / build / mobile.cfg` [here](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/master/build/mobile.cfg).

you can find mobile version under OpenLayers [github](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers) account. but you have to [deploy](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/tree/master/build) mobile version for openlayers. [Deploying (Shipping OpenLayers in your Application)](http://docs.openlayers.org/library/deploying.html) can help you...

> The OpenLayers build tool supports several different forms of
>   compressing your javascript code, and a method of describing build
>   profiles to create customized  OpenLayers builds with only the
>   components you need.
>
> When building a file, you can choose to build with several different
>   compression options to the Python-based build.py script.

i hope it helps you...